# Electrical Code Compliance Question

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, code-compliance, installation

UPDATE:

First.  Thank you guys for your responses.  My apologies for the picture issue. I couldn't figure out how to put them in the post originally so I created the link. These should be better.

[image: Wire Inscription]

[image]

Regarding some of the other responses, it is a 20A receptacle. And yes the microwave install was terrible. Along with the cord hole debacle, they also had the blower fans pointing the wrong direction. Go figure.

Also a point of clarification. It was the first time I've opened the cupboard. Apparently when my wife put the George Dickel (and other beverages) up there, she decided it wasn't necessary to mention the horrific outlet install. Or forgot. Or maybe didn't notice. Lol

---

Long time reader,  brand new poster here. I'll try to keep this brief. If you need more info, please let me know.

My microwave went out so I opened the cupboard above for the first time since I bought the house in order to start troubleshooting and this is what I found:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/TYkUTduT1rVMcK4DA

My questions are as follows:

1). Does it look like this outlet is properly grounded?

2). Is there even a chance this is code compliant?

3). If not code compliant, is it at least safe enough for now that my wife and children will not wake up to the house in flames?

Any insight you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll let the experts fill in the details, but this is definitely not to code and very unsafe. Do not continue to use it. Get an electrician to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the picture instead of a Google link?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would be happy to open a cupboard and find a surprise bottle of Tennessee sour mash; I presume it is only half full because the person who wired that receptacle drank half of the bottle just prior to doing the work...

Comment: It's not compliant, but fortunately, it looks like it should be easy to make compliant.  Assuming there's nothing else on that circuit, of course.

Comment: I fixed the picture issue by updating the original post. I hope that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Really. How much more work would it have been to connect the bare ground wire to the green ground screw on the receptacle instead of clipping it off at the end of the sheath? - The installer is a true criminal who doesn't care if his work kills your wife or anyone else.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Agreed. I think it was probably a DIY job. I've found a few things (not quite this bad) that even I, with no trade experience, could tell were done wrong or with no care about craftsmanship.

Answer (score 7):

There are two definite issues, some possible additional issues:

- Grounding

The only place ungrounded receptacles are allowed is if they are original equipment installed when a building was built (or a circuit installed) if at the time grounding was not required, or direct replacements of those receptacles. There are a bunch of factors here that indicate this receptacle was almost certainly added after grounding requirements came into effect.

So the next question is whether there is a ground wire in this cable or not. If there is a bare ground wire in the cable (can also be green, but I'm sure you won't find that in this cable) then the rest is easy.

If the cable is a two wire cable without a ground wire then you really need to replace the cable, which could be quite an ordeal depending on how it is routed behind cabinets, through the walls, possibly through the ceiling, etc.

- Box

Every receptacle, switch, electrical connection, etc. *must* be in an approved box. Some appliances and light fixtures have a built-in box for hardwired connections, but that doesn't apply here as you are installing a receptacle. The only exception is there are certain types of splices allowed for in-wall use for repairs, but that also has nothing to do with receptacle installation.

I highly recommend a metal box. You screw a metal box directly to the back of the cabinet, route the cable in through a clamp and install the receptacle. If you use a metal box and a high-quality receptacle (I would *not* trust this receptacle for reuse, and it may not be the right type anyway - more below) then it will be *self-grounding* so you connect the bare wire to the box with a grounding screw, connect hot and neutral to the receptacle, screw the receptacle into the box and put on a face plate and you're done. If you use a plastic box (ugh!) then you need to make sure you have an appropriate type for installation onto the cabinet and the ground wire must be connected directly to the receptacle.

Those are the basics. But wait, there's more!

- Wire Size

Very hard to tell from the pictures. But it looks like the wires may be 14 AWG (white cable is usually 14 AWG, but older white cable can be 12 AWG so that is no guarantee) while the receptacle looks like it is a 20A receptacle based on the horizontal slot. You can't use 14 AWG wire with a 20A receptacle or on a 20A circuit.

Is it a 15A or 20A circuit? If it is a 15A circuit then replace the receptacle with a 15A receptacle and you're OK. If it is a 20A circuit with 14 AWG wire then you have a problem. It is a small problem if this is the only kitchen receptacle on the circuit, because then you can just downgrade the circuit to 15A by replacing the breaker and you're all set. However, if there are kitchen receptacles then this is a required 20A circuit (again, if it was 15A and an older house that's OK as it is grandfathered, but if it is already 20A then you can't go backwards to 15A) and you can't downgrade it to 15A. But then you have a *big* problem because you can't have 14 AWG wire in a 20A circuit. So you need to figure that out before doing anything with this receptacle.

- GFCI

GFCI protection is most likely required. That can be done with a GFCI/receptacle here, a GFCI/receptacle *earlier* in the circuit, or with a GFCI/breaker. If this receptacle is on a circuit protected by a GFCI/breaker they you're all set. If it is not, then check if any GFCI/receptacles in the kitchen turn off this receptacle when tripped. If not then you should put a GFCI/receptacle here instead of a simple receptacle.

GFCI is actually a way to solve the *practical* safety issue of not having a ground. However, that is only code-compliant when used with circuits that were installed according to code *at the time* without a ground. A newer ungrounded circuit can't be made code-compliant simply by installing GFCI. But from a pure safety standpoint, that would be a huge improvement over a plain ungrounded receptacle.

Comment: You can see a cut off bare ground wire in one of the photos

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for such a thorough and thoughtful response. I updated my original post with better pictures. Including one that shows all the writing on the romex write. Thought that might help with the wire guage question.

Comment: I like the metal box idea. If I'm understanding correctly,  as long as the circuit is 15A I can just replace the receptacle with a 15A one and I'm good even if the wire is 14 AWG? Also, how do I figure out if it's a15A or 20A circuit? Along that line, how would I know if there are other receptacles on the circuit? Flip breakers? Thank you for the help.

Comment: The circuit is defined by the breaker - whatever breaker turns off this circuit, *which you better be doing before doing anything with the receptacles*. As far as other receptacles - after turning this off you check around the kitchen *and other rooms* to see what, if anything, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1. It is not grounded (you can see the ground wire cut off and not connected to the outlet).
2. It is not code compliant for multiple reasons (not in a junction box, not grounded, looks to likely be a 15A wire using a 20A outlet).
3. It does not appear to be an immediate fire danger if undisturbed in that condition, but needs to be rectified ASAP.  Certainly do not plug anything into it, and turn off the breaker that feeds that outlet.

What looks like happened is one of two things:

1. The cabinets were replaced at some point, and the cabinet people just drilled a hole, popped the wire through, and improperly slapped an outlet on the end.
2. The microwave is a retrofit, and the installer extended the power line from elsewhere and didn't finish it off correctly.

Of additional note is the lack of workmanship in other areas of installing the microwave, as the hole where the cord comes up is not where the cord exits the microwave, putting extra stress on the cord attached to the microwave.